# How to find a folder with Visual Studio project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I created a new project in Visual Studio and saved it. How to find a folder with the project. When I click File -> Open it shows a recent folder, not the folder with the current project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the solution of the project and select 'Open folder in Windows Explorer'
There you will find all your files related to the current project.

Answer (score 4):

In the **Solution Explorer** right-click on the solution name and select "Open folder in windows explorer"

[image: Open folder in windows explorer]