# How to identify and rename project folders in an SSIS solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis

This is related to [How to find a folder with Visual Studio project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310452/how-to-find-a-folder-with-visual-studio-project)

I have a SSIS solution in Visual Studio 2012.  It has a handful of projects under it, and each project has its own folder.  But I renamed the projects within VS.  I thought that would rename the directory folders too.  It apparently did not.  Under my main folder, I have a handful of solutions, and dozens of folders in this one directory.

How do I identify which folder belongs to which project?

Some folders need to be discarded before adding my code to git, and I do need the folder names to match the project names.  So I guess I also need to know how to rename the folder (once I identify it), so it matches the project name.

Example - a solution structure:

```
Solution DIM_Inspect
    Project Export_Inspect
    Project Extract_InspectType1
    Project Extract_InspectType2
    Project Load_Inspect
    Project Transform_Inspect
```

And my directory structure (along with a lot of other files and folders)

```
Dir DIM
      Dir Export_InspectType
      Dir Export_InspectType1
      Dir Export_InspectType2
      Dir Extract_InspectType1
      Dir Extract_InspectType2
      Dir Load_InspectType1
      Dir Load_InspectType2
      Dir Transform_Inspect
      File DIM_Inspect.sln
```

I can identify the two extracts and the transform directory because they match.  But one of those export directories should be called Export_Inspect.  One of the load directories should be called Load_Inspect.

(In other words, there was a bit of renaming and figuring things out as I created the solution.  Now, how do I figure it out and clean it up?)

**Edit**
I know all but the last folder for each project.  I can look at the files within each folder, and I see my Export_InspectType1 folder has the following files (so it's *probably* the right folder)

```
Export_Inspect.dtproj
Export_Inspect.dtproj.user
Export_Inspect.dtsx
Export_Inspections1.database
Export_Inspections1.dtproj.user
Project.params
```

And the dates for the Export_Inspect.dproj.user indicate an active file (changed today).  So I've found the folder (for one project).  Is that the only way?  And how do I change the folder name (and the .database file name) without messing everything up?

Is the only way to fix this to drop all the projects, fix the names, and then add the projects again?  (Once I've manually inspected file name and dates in each subdirectory?)

Comment: have you right clicked on your solution, click add existing project, then go through your file path to pick the right files?

Comment: @DarthTommy  I know the path - all but the last directory name.  Is my Export_Inspect project in the  Export_InspectType folder?  The Export_InspectType1 folder?  It's probably one of those three that start with Export_Inspect, but which one?  And what if it's actually under the Load_InspectType2 folder?  And once I find it, I need the folder name to be correct too.

Comment: could you look at the date modified on each of the folders/contents and guess which one is the correct folder by estimating the last time you modified that project?

Comment: @DarthTommy I was hoping for a better/easier/cleaner/safer way.  I have 41 directories, and I know at least 10+ of them are junk.  And renaming files and directories outside of studio sounds like a good way to break things altogether.

Comment: Oooh, if I rebuild all, I get output that shows the directory for each project as it rebuilds.  That's a start.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be an easy way from within VS.  But there is a way.

First, do a rebuild all on the solution.  The output will show each file and the directory it is in.  If the directory and files have a mismatch, then those are the ones that will need to be fixed.

Find a mismatch, and remove the project from the solution.

Go to the file explorer and rename the folder.  In my case, there were often some files in the folder that were kruft as well, and I put an x in front of the name (I'll remove all of those at the end).

Then, back in VS, add the existing project, browsing to the now correct folder name.

Do a rebuild all again, which will make sure no mistakes were made, and also allow checking that all folder and file names now match.